# How to call a function from another page client side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call a function from another page in order to update a point counter for an online game. As of yet, I can't figure out how to do it clientside. It needs to be done clientside, as the game is a downloaded browser-based application. I'm hosting the website using macOS Server, and I can use Jquery, but I would prefer pure JS.

Comment: Are both HTML documents served at same origin?

Comment: Are you able to control the JS on both pages?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I need to see how

Comment: It may not be possible. That's what the other users are asking for.

Comment: Can you include HTML and JavaScript that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question? See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can I do it in any other way?

Comment: I tried to use local storage to send a funtion activation using variables

Comment: What do you mean by "other way"? What have you tried to resolve your question? See links at previous comment.

Comment: @Yayguy You are incredibly unclear. What have you done so far? You haven't even answered the basic question that others have asked.

Comment: `call a function from another page` - simply, if I understand what you're asking (and I don't claim to be sure), you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly.  Why not remove the function from that 1 page and place it in an external JS file.  Then, when a page needs that function, just place the external JS file in a

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file/name.js"></script>
```

tag to load it for any page that needs it.

Comment: Would It be possible to add the script tag with javascript?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not.  To be honest, I haven't done it that way before but Javascript can add elements to the DOM.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, for clarification, would I put the functions for both pages in the external file? Would this include the add script tag code too? If not, where would I put the DOM code?

Comment: Any common (shared) functions that any number of pages can use should be put in the external JS file and linked to in the head section.  Specific functions that only apply to a certain page can go in that page.

Comment: Oh, the JS code to add the script file to the DOM can go in the common JS file.  But think about it, you would have to add a    <link>  tag to every page so that the page has access to the script.  If you do that then why do you need any JS code to add the script to the DOM?  I mean, every page will already have the     <link> tag anyway.   To be honest, I would use PHP to place the      <link> tag in certain pages.

Comment: I can't use PHP, as this isn't a hosted webpage. It's desigd to work offline as well, so the page is downloaded, with a shortcut to it, in a locked file.                                        Edit: Also, I haven't learn't PHP yet. I'm really learning all this.